# A book on logic covering peano axioms and set theory

Tags: logic, book-recommendation

I had been reading Terence tao’s analysis I , where he constructs everything from the axioms of Peano and set theory. Could someone recommend me a book which goes deeper into these aspects of logic and provides a little more context to them?

Comment: For logic and set theory, many books available; see e.g. [Torulakis](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Lectures_in_Logic_and_Set_Theory_Volume/nparMXao59QC?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=tourlakis+logic&printsec=frontcover). For Peano arithmetic (as well as set th) see also [Mendelson](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic/FS-sCQAAQBAJ?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=mendelson+logic&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I like the book on Mathematical Logic by H. D. Ebbinghaus. He covers many topics and I think there is also a section about axiomatic set theory

Comment: I have heard of principia Mathematica .How would that be as an introduction to logic? Or Nicholas bourbaki’s theory of sets?

Comment: Both are too old and too difficult...

Comment: If you want a very inexpensive option, "Set Theory and Logic" by Stoll (Dover edition is about US$22) isn't bad, and there's an entire chapter devoted solely to building from the naturals with Peano arithmetic all the way up to the reals.

Comment: Landau's *Foundations of Analysis* is worth reading just because it is so beautifully  written.

Comment: Based on your question, it sounds like you want an introduction to set theory more than one to logic. You could have a look at the book by Jech and Hrbacek.